# Winston: info and error functions: catch errors that originate in the logging itself

Tags: logging, axios, try-catch, winston

I am looking for an elegant way to get rid of the **try/catch** block here, but it seems exceptions that **occure in the logging process itself** are **not handled by Winston**, which caused my code below to not return the response although the request itself was fine.

Obviously I do

1. not want to wrap every call to *info* or *error* with try/catch
2. not want logging errors to break the program flow

```
return axios.get(url)
    .then(resp => {
      try {
        log.reqOutboundHR.info("someInfo");
        log.reqOutboundJson.info("someInfo");
      } catch (error) {
        log.logger.error("Logging failed");
      }

      return resp;
    })
    .catch((e) => catchCallback(e, "GET", url))
  }
```